# XML parsing in android

Tags: android

Hello
I have parsed the xml file. now aim is to display contents using list view as dynamiclly..
How it is possible?

Comment: Now you need to write ur custom listAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to write ur custom listAdapter, Which has the knowledge to show ur parsed data..  have a look at the below link

http://www.theleagueofpaul.com/blog/2010/03/11/android-dev-custom-listadapter/